# Copying std::vector by element more optimized than moving the whole vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am trying to pass an std::vector of custom objects by reference to a constructor that copies/moves it to another private std::vector member, but somehow copying it element by element in a for loop generates a smaller program size than when moving the whole vector at once.

Typically I have this code in my constructor:

```
constructor(std::vector<object*>& newVec)
{
  for(int i=0; i<newVec.size(); ++i)
    this->vec.push_back(newVec[i]); 
}
```

Which generates a Linux executable that has a smaller size than with using std::move like this:

```
constructor(std::vector<object*>& newVec)
{
   this->vec=std::move(newVec);
}
```

Only by switching these two snippets, I pass from 30kB size to 35kB.

PS: The object contained in the vector is different than the constructor object.

Can anyone explain to me why the former version is more optimized than the latter?

Comment: Size of binary =/= level of optimization =/= speed.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about optimizing output binary size, or are you conflating size optimization with other types of optimizations?

Comment: unused template function are not generated, so, if it is the only place you move a vector...

Comment: Try https://godbolt.org/ to compare the generated assembly.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the two snippets are not equivalent. The second will leave the argument empty, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think your answer makes sense, thanks.

Comment: The conventional forms that one would expect to see are: for a copying constructor `constructor(const std::vector<object*>& newVec): vec(newVec){}`, and for a moving `constructor(std::vector<object*>&& newVec): vec(std::move(newVec)) {}`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to pass an std::vector of custom objects by reference to a constructor that copies/moves it to another private std::vector member

In that case you should not use an lvalue reference argument.

Either pass by value, or r-value reference.

Furthermore, it would be better to initialise the member directly, instead of default initialising and then move assigning later.

> Can anyone explain to me why the former version is more optimized than the latter?

There can be many potential reasons:

- You may have not enabled compiler optimisations.
- "More optimized" is subjective. Most people care more about execution time than they care about executable size. As such, both programs can be more optimised at the same time from different perspectives.
- Using one function instead of another can increase the total number of functions used in the program. It is reasonable that this might increase the size of the executable.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with how many instructions one operation vs. the other needs. And I'd be actually surprised if the `push_back` -- which needs to check for capacity, and expand the vector if needed -- would need *fewer* operations than swapping internal references. Certainly not if the vector has many elements. My guess is that OP has already used `push_back` somewhere else in the source, so `move` adds to the size while `push_back` doesn't...

Comment: @DevSolar `Certainly not if the vector has many elements` Number of elements has no effect on number of instructions in the program unless the compiler unrolls the loop entirely, which I find unlikely.

Comment: @DevSolar The other point makes sense though; I've amended the answer.

Comment: Yes, I've rambled a bit beside the track there. Sorry. ;-)